# Click on div create dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I create some div dynamically and then i would click on one of them and show an alert. But it doesn't go. The div are into another big div that cointain them; if i click on the big div it's ok, but if i change the click event it doesn't go.

Big div:

```
<div id="combination"> </div>
```

With this function i create dynamically div (combinationCardID cointains ID of image that i want show in this div):
function showCombinationCard() {

```
var i, j;
        for (i=0; i<combinationCardID.length; i++) {
            $("#combination").append("<div id='c" + i + "' class='combcard'> </div>");
            for (j=0; j<combinationCardID[i].length; j++) {
                var image = $("#" + combinationCardID[i][j]).children("img").clone();
                $("#c" + i).append(image);
                $("#c" + i).append("  ");
            }
        }
```

And this is the click event (if i change .combcard with #combination it's ok, but this not):

```
$(".combcard").click(function() {
        divID = $(this).attr("id"); 
        alert("ok" + divID);
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

```
$("#combination").on('click', '.combcard', function() {
        divID = $(this).attr("id"); 
        alert("ok" + divID);
})
```